# BigQuery and query SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset with name and date of birth of some people, and I want to calculate their age! I helped to form the query (for BigQuery) to obtain this result? thanks

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

That should be easy for BigQuery, a lot depends on how you are storing the date of birth.

Let's say it's a string, on the form '2005-10-01'. One way to get ages is:

```
SELECT INTEGER(
    (NOW() - (TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(birthdate, ' 00:00:00'))))
    / 24/3600/365/1000/1000)
FROM users
```

Comment: How does this deal with leap years?